# Regex: 3 digits in increasing order and same number

Tags: regex

I want to check if the last 3 digits of the sequence match the 3 preceding numbers and the value of the elements in those 3 numbers must increase using Regex.

example:

- 0143123123 matching is 123
- 0143321321 not matching because the elements in those 3 numbers must not increase

i tried use that expression:

```
(\d)(?!\1)(\d)(?!\1)(?!\2)(\d)\1\2\3
```

but i only get last 3 digits of the sequence match the 3 preceding, without regard to increase

Comment: It is not possible to do greater than number comparison with regex. You can however extract the numbers using regex capture groups, turn those into integers, and do a compare of the integer values. What language do you use?

Comment: @PeterThoeny, technically this is no longer true thanks to raku regexes :-) `'0143123123' ~~ m/<((\d)(\d)(\d))><?{$0 < $1 && $1 < $2}>$0$1$2 $/;` matches `123`, but it would not match `321` on `0143321321`. But, yes, It is completelly true for 'common' regex engines

Comment: @Julio: Nice! You can execute functions/code in the replacement part of a regex search & replace in many languages, such as Perl & JavaScript. Hence my question what language Zane uses.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use:

```
(012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789)\1$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1gcwuk/1).

- `(012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789)` - Match any of these increasing sequences.
- `\1` - A backreference to match the same sequence of this 1st capture group.
- `$` - End string anchor.

Your match will be the 1st capture group.

**Note:** If you want to also account for alternations like `013|014....245|246` etc, you'd have to include those amongst those alternations. That would come down to 120 alternatives... not very pretty:

> `(012|013|014|015|016|017|018|019|023|024|025|026|027|028|029|034|035|036|037|038|039|045|046|047|048|049|056|057|058|059|067|068|069|078|079|089|123|124|125|126|127|128|129|134|135|136|137|138|139|145|146|147|148|149|156|157|158|159|167|168|169|178|179|189|234|235|236|237|238|239|245|246|247|248|249|256|257|258|259|267|268|269|278|279|289|345|346|347|348|349|356|357|358|359|367|368|369|378|379|389|456|457|458|459|467|468|469|478|479|489|567|568|569|578|579|589|678|679|689|789)\1$`

Maybe your app has a way to post-process the capture group as a better alternative.